# Get Friends who have liked a particular page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using JavaScript to retrieve friends's info as follows:

```
FB.api('/me/friends', {fields:'name,id,hometown,education'}, function(response){

var l=''
    $.each(response.data,function(idx,val){
    l=l+val.id+(idx<response.data.length-1?',':'')
    });

FB.api("likes?ids="+l,function(res){
    allLikes = res;
    });
}
```

Using the above code, I have successfully retrieved all likes of all of the user's friends. I wanted to check which of the user's friends have liked a particular page. The response data is about 1.5MBs. I have to iterate through individual likes of all of the friends one-by-one to figure this out. How to retrieve info only those friends who have already liked a particular page?

Comment: I am new to FB APIs.. Could you give me a basic example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the user ids of the user's friend who have liked a particular `<page_id>` using following FQL query.

```
FB.api({
     method: 'fql.query',
     query: 'select uid from page_fan where page_id=<page_id>
              and uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())'
   },function(response){
        //do what you want to do with user ids (uid) you got
});
```